# Entity Relationships Not Defined

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API application, I am having trouble relating entities in Entity Framework Core. When I send a GET request to the Controller through Postman all of the Model's records are returned, but the navigation properties for their related entities come back null. Unfortunately, there are no errors or exceptions thrown either. The (simplified) code is as follows:

```
//DBContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(p => p.Location)
                .WithMany(l => l.People)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.Location_ID);
        });
    }


//Person Model
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int People_ID { get; set; }

    public int? Location_ID { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

//Location Model
public partial class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Location_ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I understand it, because I dictated the two Models are related using the Fluent API in the OnModelCreating method, the properties should be 'Eagerly Loaded'. Why is this not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand it, because I dictated the two Models are related using the Fluent API in the OnModelCreating method, the properties should be 'Eagerly Loaded'

You understand it wrong. The [Eager Loading](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#eager-loading) behavior is not implicit (like lazy loading), you have to explicitly request it using `Include` / `ThenInclude` methods.

For instance, the following will return the `Person` entities with `Location` property populated:

```
return db.Set<Person>().Include(p => p.Location);
```

Comment: At what level would this return statement be declared at?

Comment: As per my Database-First EF generated Models, I have the DbSets declared at the bottom of my DbContext file. I then extend the DbContext to a 'method repository' class which explicitly calls the DbSets through the DbContext-loaded property e.g. `return _db.People;`

Comment: `_db.Set<Person>()` is the same as `_db.People`. Where and how exactly do you implement the eager loading is beyond the scope of your current question, which I believe the answer is covering.

Comment: You are right, that question is out of scope. This answer did work for me, so thank you very much for your help!